# ASCII validator in a django model field fails for plain English

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model which has following fields with an `ascii` validator:

```
def is_ascii(value):
    try:
        value.decode('ascii')
    except:
        raise ValidationError('Please enter all your details in english characters!')


first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=32, blank=False, null=False, validators=[is_ascii])
last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=32, blank=False, null=False, validators=[is_ascii])
email = models.EmailField("Email", blank=False, null=False, unique=True,
                          error_messages=email_errors, validators=[is_ascii])
```

It used to work as expected on Python 2 but the validator fails on Python 3. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `EmailField` inherits the `CharField` which is a string up to max_length. Strings in Python 3.x do not have a `decode` method, but bytes do. 
You can use an ASCII regex validation instead

Comment: Thank you! I should not have used generic except.

Answer (score 4):

You're catching all exceptions, which hides what the problem is. **Never, ever** do this.

If you remove the try/except, you'll see what the *actual* error is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

That's because in Python 3, all strings are unicode, and you can't *decode* a unicode string, you can only *encode* it. If you used the correct method, you would get the correct result, which is UnicodeEncodeError when the string contains a non-ASCII value. You should *only* catch that specific exception.

```
def is_ascii(value):
    try:
        value.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        raise ValidationError('Please enter all your details in english characters!')
```

Comment: Your proposition is right and it'll give me the exact problem over there. But this would not have solved it since it was an attribute error. Thanks!

Comment: I'll go with the regex validation.